# PHP логирование. Как заставить скрипт писать весь лог в один файл?

Tags: ajax, php, post, get, javascript

В php сильно не разбираюсь, потребовалось логировать результаты js-тестов в файл.
В общем вот php скрипт, который пишет логи из YUI-тестов в файл:

```
$serverTime = Date('YmdHis');
$logFile = "result/log".$serverTime.".html";

$logFileHandle = fopen($logFile, 'a');
$messageReceived = trim($_REQUEST["msg"]);
fwrite($logFileHandle, $messageReceived."\r\n");
fclose($logFileHandle);
```

Во время теста данный скрипт создает несколько файлов логов. Мне нужно только один на время работы теста. Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Есть мысль взять время прямо в начале теста через js и передать через ajax скрипту для названия файла. Видимо это все из-за того, что я создаю запрос при каждом логе теста.

Comment: не, плохая затея) см ответ Palmervan'a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А сколько длится тест по времени? `$serverTime = Date('YmdHis');` каждую секунду создает файл при условии ежесекндного обращения к скрипту!

Попробуйте так `$serverTime = Date('Ymd');` создаст файл на 1 день.

К тому же нужно писать условие

```
if(file_exists($logFile)) { /*some actions*/ }
```

Ну а дальше по смыслу.

Comment: либо `$serverTime = Date('YmdH0000');` чтобы почасовые логи были к примеру, наверное так лучше будет... в любом случае зависит от "теста"